# center my text not only horizontally but also vertically in constraint layout edit pane

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In `ConstraintLayout`, I have a TextView, I have set the alignment to align **center** in layout editor pane:

[image]

I clicked the middle one in above screenshot.

Then, my text looks like this:

[image]

It is centered horizontally but not vertically, and in `ConstraintLayout` editor pane, I just can't find a button for vertical center my text.

How to vertically & horizontally center my text in `ConstraintLayout` editor pane?

Comment: post your some relevant  pic of code

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: try to set ` android:gravity="center_vertical"` in TextView property in xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `textAlignment` you can use `gravity` attribute:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

`XML` sources of your `TextView` will be like that:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="174dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Also, you can find this attribute in `Design` view:

[image]

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I expected. I didn't realize there are more attributes could be set in the editing pane.

Answer (score 0):

What you did right there is align the text inside the TextView both horizontally and vertically.

You can check this by setting the background of TextView to some color.

Now if you want to vertically center the TextView with the parent ViewGroup which in this case is ConstraintLayout you can do

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

What this does is, all the sides are attached to all four sides of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Put code like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stat_1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="10"
    android:textColor="#777"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stat_2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider_1" />
```